# Using Boost in Django Haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm new to haystack and I'm stuck. I have a model with an integer field (between 1 - 10) and I want to increase the relevance of the results based on the value.

Currently I have this in my SearchIndex model:

```
def prepare(self, obj):
    data = super(Items, self).prepare(obj)
    data['boost'] = obj.weight
    return data
```

My query is:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(title__in=query_list)[:40]
```

It doen't seem to be working though, the results are exactly the same as before I added the prepare function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by switching my search backend to solr from xapian.